# Regex to capture single quoted strings

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I am using .net regex engine and I need a regex pattern to capture substrings in single quotes.

What I have:

```
(?<!\\p{L})['‘]+(s['’] \\p{Lu}|['’]\\p{L}|[^‘'’\r])*['’]+((?<!s['’])(?! \\p{Lu})|(?!\\p{L}))
```

How I think it works:

1. a non-capturing non-alphanumeric followed by 1-many single quotes

   `(?<!\\p{L})['‘]+`
2. 0-many groups of ("s"+apostrophe+space+uppercase letter OR apostrophe+lowercaseletter OR not an apostrophe or line break)
   `(s['’] \\p{Lu}|['’]\\p{L}|[^‘'’\r])*`
3. 1-many closing quotes
   `['’]+`
4. Validation at the end: (not s+apostrophe behind AND not space+uppercaseletter in front) OR not a letter in front 
   ((?

How it should work:
eg. "This is my 'Monkey's Chimp' farm"
Desired result: 'Monkey's Chimp'
What I currently get: 'Monkey'

Explanation: 's should not be treated as a closing quote. Nor should s' if it is followed by a space and another uppercase letter.

Question: Why does the engine stop at the apostrophe in monkey's? In section 2 above, it should capture "'s" and then keep going. The engine is greedy, right?

Any help gratefully received

Comment: working fine here https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/2

Comment: Working in [.Net too](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c!%5cp%7bL%7d)%5b%27%e2%80%98%5d%2b(s%5b%27%e2%80%99%5d+%5cp%7bLu%7d%7c%5b%27%e2%80%99%5d%5cp%7bL%7d%7c%5b%5e%e2%80%98%27%e2%80%99%5cr%5d)*%5b%27%e2%80%99%5d%2b((%3f%3c!s%5b%27%e2%80%99%5d)(%3f!+%5cp%7bLu%7d)%7c(%3f!%5cp%7bL%7d))&i=This+is+my+%27Monkey%27s+Chimp%27+farm), as long you don't use double backslashes. Are you over-escaping? Should be `@"\p{L}"` or `"\\p{L}"`, not `@"\\p{L}"`.

Comment: My apologies, and thanks to Maroun for editing the post so that the regexes can actually be seen. I made a mistake in the example. "in this example 'Monkey's Chimp' is found correctly". "In this example 'Monkey's Chimp (no closing quote)" returns "Monkey", which is undesirable. In this case I would like the regex to not be a success.

Comment: What about [`\B['‘]+(?:s['’] \p{Lu}|['’]\p{L}|[^‘'’\r])*['’]+\B`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cB%5b%27%e2%80%98%5d%2b(%3f%3as%5b%27%e2%80%99%5d+%5cp%7bLu%7d%7c%5b%27%e2%80%99%5d%5cp%7bL%7d%7c%5b%5e%e2%80%98%27%e2%80%99%5cr%5d)*%5b%27%e2%80%99%5d%2b%5cB&i=%22In+this+example+%27Monkey%27s+Chimp%0d%0a%22In+this+example+%27Monkey%27s+Chimp%27)? `\B` will match at non-word boundary positions, thus disallowing any letters, digits and underscores be right before the apostrophes and after them.

Comment: stribizhev, thanks very much. That is definitely an improvement. I am still getting matches I dont want though:  EG. Regex.Match("This is a 'Monkeys' Chimp", "\\B['‘]+(?:s['’] \\p{Lu}|['’]\\p{L}|[^‘'’\\r])*['’]+\\B").Value
= "'Monkeys'"
Because the s' is followed by " \\p{Lu}" the engine should carry on looking for a closing quote (in my understanding), and never find one. I can see that this part of the regex is working: Regex.Match("This is a 'Monkeys' Chimp", "s['’] \\p{Lu}").Value
= "s' C"....so I am not sure what the problem is?

Comment: What about this [`\B['‘]+(?:s['’] \p{Lu}|['’]\p{L}|[^‘'’\r])*(?<!s)['’]+\B`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cB%5b%27%e2%80%98%5d%2b(%3f%3as%5b%27%e2%80%99%5d+%5cp%7bLu%7d%7c%5b%27%e2%80%99%5d%5cp%7bL%7d%7c%5b%5e%e2%80%98%27%e2%80%99%5cr%5d)*(%3f%3c!s)%5b%27%e2%80%99%5d%2b%5cB&i=%22In+this+example+%27Monkey%27s+Chimp%0d%0a%22In+this+example+%27Monkey%27s+Chimp%27%0d%0aThis+is+a+%27Monkeys%27+Chimp)? (Please do not forget `@` before the username when addressing someone via comments).

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go. The technique of "Lookaround" seemed a good fit.

I'm also using .NET

```
(?!'s\b)'.*?'(?!s\b)
```

- [Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!'s\b)`

  - [Match the character string “'s” literally (case sensitive)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `'s`
  - [Assert position at a word boundary (position preceded or followed—but not both—by a Unicode letter, digit, or underscore)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b`
- [Match the character “'” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `'`
- [Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) `.*?`

  - [Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) `*?`
- [Match the character “'” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `'`
- [Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!s\b)`

  - [Match the character “s” literally (case sensitive)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `s`
  - [Assert position at a word boundary (position preceded or followed—but not both—by a Unicode letter, digit, or underscore)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b`